# How do I dynamically update sql column in one table based on value in another table

Tags: mysql

There are 2 Tables,

```
Reviews Table Contains:
Overall(InnoDB):
(value can be 1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5 .... 5.0)

Stats(MyISAM):
(contains columns R1.0,R1.5,....R5.0)
```

So when overall value is `5.0 I` want to only increment `R5.0` by 1 and when overall value is `1.5`, I want to increment only 1.5 by 1.

I am using `MySQLi`, how do I achieve this with trigger in `phpmyadmin` ? Any help would be great.

Comment: You need a trigger for what kind of operation? `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or `DELETE`? Or you just need a `update`?

Comment: Is there a column that relates the tables, like an item ID?

Comment: Trigger for either INSERT or UPDATE. There is a column that relates the table, say ItemID.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` between the tables. Then increment the columns in `Stats` conditional on the value in `Reviews`.

```
UPDATE Stats AS s
JOIN Reviews AS r ON s.itemid = r.itemid
SET s.`R1.0` = IF(r.Overall = 1.0, s.`R1.0` + 1, s.`R1.0`),
    s.`R1.5` = IF(r.Overall = 1.5, s.`R1.5` + 1, s.`R1.5`),
    s.`R2.0` = IF(r.Overall = 2.0, s.`R2.0` + 1, s.`R2.0`),
    ...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for providing the code, but If I use it as trigger either in After Update or After Insert, phpmyadmin is not accepting entry. Like my review won't even appear and MySQL is in strict mode.

Comment: Add an update to your question showing how you're trying to do the trigger and what error you're getting.